# .cif .pdb conversion with python

Tags: python, pdb

can you please give me an advice how to convert .cif files into .pdb preferably using python?

Thanks in advance!
Best,
Balint Biro

Comment: Its certainly doable and PyMol will also do this. A number of site members hold this expertise. What I think is that the format you are downloading in is cif rather than what you want which is pdb. If that is the case please modify your question

Comment: Dear Michael,yes, that is the case but I cant see how should I modify my question...

Comment: Using the [edit] button :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Michael said PyMOL can do this. PyMOL is not only an app, but also a python package —installed [via conda](https://anaconda.org/schrodinger/pymol) not via the regular download (you can have both).

```
import pymol2
with pymol2.PyMOL() as pymol:
     pymol.cmd.load(infile,'myprotein')
     pymol.cmd.save(infile.replace('.cif', '.pdb'), selection='myprotein')
```

This runs the parallelisable instance, so you can have that context manager block running on how many threads or processes you fancy.

Comment: Dear Matteo, thanks for that. Unfortunately it gives me back the error that 'name 'infile' is not defined'.

Comment: @BalintBiro You need to change that part so that it matches the name of the file you are using.

Comment: Hi @BalintBiro please upvote or mark 'accepted'. This is the answer. You need to define the location of the infile before the `with` statement starts, thats why you have the error. You need a certain degree of coding proficiency.